# Unfair dice question

Tags: probability, dice

A random experiment consists of rolling an unfair, six-sided die. The digit 6 is three times as likely to appear as each of the numbers 2 and 4. Each of the numbers 2 and 4 are twice as likely to appear as each of the numbers 1, 3 and 5
Suppose that the random variable X, is assigned the value of the digit that appears when the die is rolled. What is the expected value of X?

So i got that the added weight is 13
Therefore 6 would have 6/13 chances of getting rolled.
I still dont know x, help please

Answer (score 2):

You get the expected value of X by multiplying each possible number with its probability and adding up:

$1\cdot P(X=1)+2\cdot P(X=2)+...+6\cdot P(X=6)$